# Cannot use (type []byte) as type string in argument to strconv.ParseFloat issue

Tags: go, gpio

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop/go $ go run shell1.go
```

As result i am getting:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop/go $ go run shell1.go
# command-line-arguments
./shell1.go:29: undefined: n
./shell1.go:29: cannot use b (type []byte) as type string in argument to strconv.ParseFloat
./shell1.go:32: undefined: n
```

Go file (`shell1.go`) code  is:

```
package main

import (
    //    "net/http"
    //    "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
    "strconv"
    "time"
    //"bytes"
    //"encoding/binary"
)
import _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
import _ "database/sql"

func main() {
    for {
        time.Sleep(10 * time.Millisecond)
        cmd := exec.Command("gpio.bash")

        b, err := cmd.Output()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        n, _ = strconv.ParseFloat(b, 10)
        fmt.Println(string(b))
        break
    }

    fmt.Println("Button pressed!!! ", n)

}
```

Content of (`gpio.bash`) file is just one command to read gpio

```
 #!/bin/bash
gpio read 29
```

Comment: Change `n, _ = strconv.ParseFloat(b, 10)` to `n, _ := strconv.ParseFloat(string(b), 10)`. Your compiler errors have the exact information you'd need to fix this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are working with a [command](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Command) here, which can of course execute just about anything.

The function is purposely generic, as the true return type varies depending on what you executed. Thus, when you call the [output](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.Output) method, you are given a slice of bytes (very generic!). Here is its signature:

```
func (c *Cmd) Output() ([]byte, error)
```

If you know that the bytes will always be a string, then you simply have to do a type conversion to a string:

```
n, _ := strconv.ParseFloat(string(b), 10)
```